# What is the genre of movies with multiple interrelated plots called?

Tags: genre

There are a lot of movies these days with multiple interrelated plots. There are huge number of examples like [Crash](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0375679/?ref_=fn_al_tt_1), [Amores Perros](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0245712/?ref_=sr_1), [Babel](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0449467/) and many others.

Is there a specific name given or applicable to such genre of movies ?How do you otherwise search for such movies ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answer is [hyperlink cinema](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperlink_cinema) . Here is the [link of movies at imdb](http://www.imdb.com/list/ITT0m4IvmlY/?start=1&view=detail&sort=release_date_us:desc&defaults=1&lists=ITT0m4IvmlY&scb=0.17880748910829425) .

It is exactly defined as

> hyperlink cinema as films where the characters or action reside in separate stories, but a connection or influence between those disparate stories is slowly revealed to the audience

I got the answer from [ankit's link though](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/10441/3559).

Answer (score 5):

These kind of films are called [Anthology film](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anthology_film). From Wikipedia:

> An anthology film (also known as an omnibus film, package film, or portmanteau film) is a subgenre of films consisting of several different short films, often tied together by only a single theme, premise, or brief interlocking event (often a turning point). Sometimes each one is directed by a different director.

Comment: not quite! I followed your link there is another genre called hyperlink movies. That's the one I am referring to. The difference is that anthology films show one story after another while hyperlink movies show bits of every one. The examples that I am referring to are part of hyperlink movies. Though I am able to find any such term at IMDB. Thanks anyway !

Comment: I am glad you find what you searching for.